# Cannot forward attachments in Outlook

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have noticed with some of my users that they are unable to forward or send attachments as a reply using `Outlook 2016` on `Windows 7`.

**Update:** I have also noticed this with some of our `Windows 10` users, same issue with the same solution.

I realized that it is because the original email is sent in a **Plain Text** format, and does not convert properly even though settings are configured to do so.

[image]

[image]

This seems to have been a recent issue with only some users on the same version of Outlook.  Possibly related to office updates released recently.

[**Source**](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-outlook/outlook-2016-cannot-forward-attachment/485b4010-1987-4da7-ae3a-ff07ebf60c6a?page=1&auth=1)

> Hi everyone,
>
> Sounds like you've run into a bug that was caused by a recent update.
>   I'd like to confirm that the Outlook team is aware of this issue and
>   working on it. Thank you for bringing it to our attention, and
>   apologies for any inconvenience this has caused you. As Matthew
>   mentions, the only workaround is to change the message format to HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized that update **KB4011626** was the source of this problem.

You can find more details about this update [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011626/descriptionofthesecurityupdateforoutlook2016january9-2018)

> Known issues in this security update After you install this security
>   update, attachments are removed when you forward plain text emails.
>
> To work around this issue, save the attachments locally, reattach, and
>   then send the email. Save the attachments to a temporary location.
>   Open the email, and then select Reply, Reply All, or Forward. Add the
>   attachments that you saved in step 1. Send the email. Microsoft is
>   researching this problem and will post more information in this
>   article when the information becomes available.

While I am not usually one to recommend un-installing "security updates", I figured I would share that un-installing **KB4011626** fixed the problem for the time being since the provided workaround can be a bit strenuous for the average user.

I currently have the update disapproved in our environment until another update is present.

---

**Feel free to provide other solutions if you find any.**

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and there is a hotfix, it worked for me!

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011123/january-22-2018-update-for-outlook-2016-kb4011123

Originally found here: 
http://www.mgdking.com/post/outlook-2016-cannot-forward-attachments-kb4011626-issue